# Getting rid of white space and characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I am creating a password generator that combines numbers and string from a list. However, when I try to add them together into one variable, it adds brackets, apostrophes, and white space.

I have tried printing the two variables together, but there is still white space. I have looked at tutorials for formatted print, but they are very confusing. Also, when I try to use .strip() and .replace() it says 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'.

(PS. The password generator imports a text file with the phonetic alphabet(phoneticlist). Also, the generator has different modes. The 'triv' part stands for trivial difficulty.

```
import random
passnum = random.randint(100,999)
phonum = random.randint(0,26)
trivpastr = (phoneticlist[phonum])
trivpass = trivpastr, str(passnum)
trivpass.replace("'","")
trivpass.strip()
print(trivpass)
```

I think the two solutions I am looking for here are either to format the print so the output has no spaces, or to figure out how to properly use strip and replace so it prints it out properly. 
What I am looking for is an output that is like, 'alpha234' without space or other characters.

Comment: `trivpass = f'{random.randint(100,999)}{random.choice(phoneticlist)}'`. If there's still a need to remove `'` and whitespace from `trivpass`, that would be better handled by removing them from `phoneticlist` so that they can't be added in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line returns a tuple not a string

```
trivpass = trivpastr, str(passnum)
```

If you want to concatenate `trivpastr` and `passnum` you need to use `+` operator like this

```
trivpass = trivpastr + str(passnum)
trivpass = trivpass.replace("'","")
trivpass = trivpass.strip()
```

`replace` and `.strip()` methods are not in-place methods. they return new strings and don't change the string you used.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need:

```
trivpass = trivpastr.strip().replace("'", '') + str(passnum)
```

The problem is `trivpass = trivpastr, str(passnum)` is creating a tuple and not a string as you assume.

**Code**:

```
import random

passnum = random.randint(100,999)
phonum = random.randint(0,26)
trivpastr = phoneticlist[phonum]

# Change in below line
trivpass = trivpastr.strip().replace("'", '') + str(passnum)

print(trivpass)
```